# Doing RSA integration with My App giving Error Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class

Tags: android

i m new to Android please help i get below error line in logcat and my app get Hang..
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class com.rsa.mobile.android.authenticationsdk.methods.eye.EyeBaseFragment ,com.rsa.mobile.android.authenticationsdk.methods.eye.EyeEnrollmentFragment

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please paste the code as text into your question then highlight and press Ctrl+K this allows us to copy and paste your code into our IDEs and help identify the problem. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know what code you need to include